# How to load a single icon from the resources of another file using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, resources, icons

I want to load an icon (from another file) which doesn't have multiple icons embedded in it (it's not an icon group).
I don't know its size.
I use now this code to retrieve the handle of the icon and use it with a TIcon.Handle:

```
function ResourceToIconHandle(hFile: hModule; IDname: PChar): HICON;
var
   hGicon1,
   hLoadIcon1: THandle;
   pGIcon1: Pointer;
begin
   hGicon1 := FindResource(hFile, IDName, RT_ICON);
   if hGicon1 <> 0 then
   begin
      hLoadIcon1 := LoadResource(hFile, hGicon1);
      pGicon1 := LockResource(hLoadIcon1);
      Result := CreateIconfromResource(pGicon1,
           SizeofResource(hFile, hGicon1),
           True,
           $00030000);
   end;
end;
```

Yes, it's only a part of the code (if you want I'll show all).
It works with only one problem: CreateIconfromResource function is giving me any icon streched at 32x32:

[image: 1]

But I want to get the icons at their original resolution:
[image: 2]

I know that CreateIconfromResource is designed to get them at the same resolution, that's why I'm looking for another function.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try calling `CreateIconFromResourceEx` passing the appropriate size? I also don't understand why you don't use an icon group, but that's not the point of the question I guess.

Comment: @David Heffernan I know about CreateIconFromResourceEx but I don't know how to find their resolution because I'm loading them from another exe file. In that exe may be a icon group or jus an icon. I solved with the icon group using CreateIconFromResourceEx but I need to load single icons at their original resolution.

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes, your idea with CreateIconFromResourceEx  was good, I just had to set the parameters right. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, you have enough reputation now to upvote as well as accept answers.

Comment: Yes, I noticed and I voted. Thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `CreateIconFromResourceEx` instead of `CreateIconFromResource`.

`CreateIconFromResourceEx` lets you provide desired width/height, while `CreateIconFromResource` is using default system mertics for those (such as explained for `LR_DEFAULTSIZE`):

> Uses the width or height specified by the system metric values for
>   cursors or icons, if the cxDesired or cyDesired values are set to
>   zero. If this flag is not specified and cxDesired and cyDesired are
>   set to zero, the function uses the actual resource size. If the
>   resource contains multiple images, the function uses the size of the
>   first image.

Comment: Thank you. I used with/without LR_DEFAULTSIZE and zero for cxDesired  and cyDesired but still gets 32x32 for all. I don't have the values for cxDesired and cyDesired to pass them to the function because I don't know the width and height of the icons (I'm loading them from another file).

Comment: The API requires that you either (a) request specific size (b) let API to load default system size (c) instruct to read icon with size of the first icon in group. If you are not happy with this (as you possibly are), you have to enumerate available icon sizes first. To do so, you need to lock resource data and access it directly. See these links on resource data format for icons: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Check this out for enumerating available icon sizes: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/ICON_Resources.aspx?display=Print

Comment: I understand, thank you. But it seems that the problem was elsewhere and setting 0 for the last 3 parameters indeed works. Thank you very much for your help. I will mark your answer as good.

Comment: Most likely it worked because largest icon goes first, see (c) in comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Roman R. is probably right, but I also add that you must set proper dimensions of TIcon object **before** setting its Handle.

Comment: Thank you. The actual code works for RT_GROUP_ICON without setting the proper dimensions of TIcon object before setting its Handle. Anyway I don't know how to set the proper dimensions (you're talking about width and height?) because I don't know the width and the height of the icon.

Comment: Setting of width and height is needed before loading from stream. Loading from Handle probably will be ok without them. Sorry, I forgot that. It is almost two years since I has looked into TIcon sources :(